# IIS URL Rewrite forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a problem with the IIS rewrite 2 and ASP.NET forms authentication. When the user visits https://mydomain.tld/mypage, ASP forms authentication redirects the user to https://mydomain.tld/login/login.aspx. Once authenticated, they are redirected back to https://mydomain.tld/mypage. I want to rewrite the URL https://mydomain.tld/login/login.aspx with https://mydomain.tld/mypage/login.aspx, but with no success. I have added the following rule on the web.config for 'login':

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="RewriteMypage" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="^(.*)/login/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/mypage/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also tried adding the same code on the web.config for 'mypage', but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you updated the login url in the authentication section?

Comment: Also when you say I'd doesn't work. What exactly is happening, application error or a browser redirect error etc? Please extend your question

Comment: @MisterSmith there is no error, the login page is served with the regular url, no rewrite happens. Right now I'm reinstalling the URL rewrite, this time using the Web Platform, and installing the Failed Request Tracing tool to check what is causing this